# Material-ui toolbar not rendering the expected output

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to display the toolbar using material-ui according to the documentation as follows.

My toobar.js files looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import FontIcon from 'material-ui/FontIcon';
import NavigationExpandMoreIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/expand-more';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import {Toolbar, ToolbarGroup, ToolbarSeparator, ToolbarTitle} from 'material-ui/Toolbar';

export default class ToolbarExamplesSimple extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 3,
    };
  };

 handleChange(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({value})
};
  render() {
    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <ToolbarGroup firstChild={true}>
          <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="All Broadcasts" />
            <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="All Voice" />
            <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="All Text" />
            <MenuItem value={4} primaryText="Complete Voice" />
            <MenuItem value={5} primaryText="Complete Text" />
            <MenuItem value={6} primaryText="Active Voice" />
            <MenuItem value={7} primaryText="Active Text" />
          </DropDownMenu>
        </ToolbarGroup>
        <ToolbarGroup>
          <ToolbarTitle text="Options" />
          <FontIcon className="muidocs-icon-custom-sort" />
          <ToolbarSeparator />
          <RaisedButton label="Create Broadcast" primary={true} />
          <IconMenu
            iconButtonElement={
              <IconButton touch={true}>
                <NavigationExpandMoreIcon />
              </IconButton>
            }
          >
            <MenuItem primaryText="Download" />
            <MenuItem primaryText="More Info" />
          </IconMenu>
        </ToolbarGroup>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a div element in my html page with id 'app'. I am trying to bind the toolbar to that div using following code in my app.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import ToolbarExamplesSimple from './toolbar'; // Our custom react component

injectTapEventPlugin();

render(<ToolbarExamplesSimple />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And following error is displayed in the console:

```
 *Warning: Failed context type: Required context `muiTheme` was not specified in `Toolbar`.
    in Toolbar (created by ToolbarExamplesSimple)
    in ToolbarExamplesSimple*
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is rendered in the end?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr , actually, it didn't render anything. I found following error in console : Warning: Failed context type: Required context `muiTheme` was not specified in `Toolbar`.
    in Toolbar (created by ToolbarExamplesSimple)
    in ToolbarExamplesSimple

Comment: Update please your question with this information. I'll give an answer in short time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your app component in the `<MuiThemeProvider>`. Take a look [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage).

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import ToolbarExamplesSimple from './toolbar'; // Our custom react component

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider>
    < ToolbarExamplesSimple />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```